# I have list of items each item have mat-spinner-button I need to show the loading spinner onClick of the button on the item how to do that?

Tags: angular, angular-material

each time I click on the button the spinner is displayed on the all buttons on the list how could I fix this issue I tried to add the index to the condition but it didn't work, like this 
`*ngIf="isLoading && i"`, and like this `*ngIf="isLoading && indx==i"`

```js
view(index: any) {
    debugger
    this.loaded = false
    this.isLoading = true
 
    this.getBooking(this.arrUnverifiedBookings[index]['booking_ref'])
  }
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let objbooking of arrUnverifiedBookings; index as i">
   <div *ngIf="i%2==0" class="Bookingrowblue">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-2 borderright paddingcarcol">
      <img src="{{publicMedia}}/cars/{{objbooking?.car.type}}-{{objbooking?.car.model}}-1.png"
       class="carimg">
     </div>
     <div class="col-1 align-center paddingarrow">
      <img src="./assets/images/white arrow.svg" class="arrowwhite">
     </div>
     <div class="col-2 borderright paddingcar">
      <h5><strong>{{objbooking?.car.brand_desc}} {{objbooking?.car.model}}</strong></h5>
      <p>{{objbooking?.car.type_desc}}</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-2 paddingarrow">
      <img *ngIf="objbooking?.selfie_filename" src="{{mediaUrl}}{{objbooking?.selfie_filename}}"
       class="idimg">
     </div>
     <div class="col-3 borderright paddingarrow paddingleft linehight">
      <h5><strong>{{objbooking?.account_name}}</strong></h5>
      <p>ID: {{objbooking?.account_code}}</p>
      <p>Booking Reference: {{objbooking?.booking_ref}}</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-2 paddingarrow linehight paddingpricecol">
      <p class="colorwhite font12 paddingprice">Price for {{objbooking?.booking_units}}
       {{objbooking?.booking_units_desc}}</p>
      <h5><strong>{{objbooking?.total_charge}}</strong><span class="font12"> SAR</span></h5>
      <!-- <button   class="buttonbook" (click) = "view(i)"   >View Details</button> -->
      <button class="buttonbook" mat-raised-button (click)="view(i)">View Details
       <mat-icon>
        <mat-spinner color="primary" *ngIf="isLoading" diameter="20">
        </mat-spinner>
       </mat-icon>
      </button>
     </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take `isLoading` as an **array** in which you will store `true`/`false` based on the index of the button you will click.

Try like this:

.ts

```
isLoading = []

view(index: any) {

    this.isLoading[index] = true
    ...
}
```

.html

```
<mat-spinner color="primary" *ngIf="isLoading[i]" diameter="20">
</mat-spinner>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-progress-spinner-hsbfxx?embed=1&file=src/app/button-overview-example.ts)**